# Android - Alarm Clock error

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I download alarm app because I need see how it works. GNU License.

But I can't run it. When I clicked on (something?), I get this error:

```
        08-03 14:40:26.154: E/AndroidRuntime(255):  at com.codeskraps.talarkam.TalarkamActivity.onResume(TalarkamActivity.java:108)
```

Some of the code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate Started");

    setContentView(R.layout.alarm_controller);

    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    tpAlarm = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.tpAlarm);
    chkSnooze = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkSnooze);
    etxtSnoozeMin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etxtSnoozeMin);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSetAlarm);
    btnSetTone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSetTone);
    chkVolume = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkVolume);
    skbVolume = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.skbVolume);

    button.setOnClickListener(setAlarmListener);
    btnSetTone.setOnClickListener(this);
}


protected void onResume() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onResume");
    super.onResume();

    tpAlarm.setCurrentHour(prefs.getInt(M_HOUR, 0));
    tpAlarm.setCurrentMinute(prefs.getInt(M_MINT, 0));
    chkSnooze.setChecked(prefs.getBoolean(M_SNOOZE, false));
    etxtSnoozeMin.setText(prefs.getString(SNOOZE_T, "0"));
    chkVolume.setChecked(prefs.getBoolean(CHKVOLUME, false));
    skbVolume.setProgress(prefs.getInt(SKBVOLUME, 0));

    Uri alarmUri = Uri.parse(prefs.getString(TONE, null));
    Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, alarmUri);
    if (ringtone != null) {
        String name = ringtone.getTitle(this);
        btnSetTone.setText(name);
    } else
        btnSetTone.setText(getString(R.string.btn_SetAlarmTone));

    if (prefs.getBoolean(FIRST_LAUNCH, true)) {
        Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
        checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
        startActivityForResult(checkIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

        editor.putBoolean(FIRST_LAUNCH, false);
        editor.commit();
    }
}


protected void onPause() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onPause");
    super.onPause();

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

    editor.putInt(M_HOUR, tpAlarm.getCurrentHour());
    editor.putInt(M_MINT, tpAlarm.getCurrentMinute());
    editor.putBoolean(M_SNOOZE, chkSnooze.isChecked());
    editor.putString(SNOOZE_T, etxtSnoozeMin.getText().toString());
    editor.putBoolean(CHKVOLUME, chkVolume.isChecked());
    editor.putInt(SKBVOLUME, skbVolume.getProgress());

    editor.commit();
}
```

LogCat:

```
08-03 14:40:25.684: D/TalarkamActivity(255): onCreate Started
08-03 14:40:25.965: D/dalvikvm(255): GC freed 599 objects / 51056 bytes in 86ms
08-03 14:40:26.134: D/TalarkamActivity(255): onResume
08-03 14:40:26.144: D/AndroidRuntime(255): Shutting down VM
08-03 14:40:26.144: W/dalvikvm(255): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
08-03 14:40:26.144: E/AndroidRuntime(255): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
08-03 14:40:26.154: E/AndroidRuntime(255): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.codeskraps.talarkam/com.codeskraps.talarkam.TalarkamActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
08-03 14:40:26.154: E/AndroidRuntime(255):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2950)
08-03 14:40:26.154: E/AndroidRuntime(255):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2965)
08-03 14:40:26.154: E/AndroidRuntime(255):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2516)
08-03 14:40:26.154: E/AndroidRuntime(255):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
08-03 14:40:26.154: E/AndroidRuntime(255):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
08-03 14:40:26.154: E/AndroidRuntime(255):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-03 14:40:26.154: E/AndroidRuntime(255):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-03 14:40:26.154: E/AndroidRuntime(255):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
08-03 14:40:26.154: E/AndroidRuntime(255):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-03 14:40:26.154: E/AndroidRuntime(255):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-03 14:40:26.154: E/AndroidRuntime(255):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
08-03 14:40:26.154: E/AndroidRuntime(255):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
08-03 14:40:26.154: E/AndroidRuntime(255):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-03 14:40:26.154: E/AndroidRuntime(255): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
08-03 14:40:26.154: E/AndroidRuntime(255):  at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:420)
08-03 14:40:26.154: E/AndroidRuntime(255):  at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:410)
08-03 14:40:26.154: E/AndroidRuntime(255):  at android.net.Uri.parse(Uri.java:382)
08-03 14:40:26.154: E/AndroidRuntime(255):  at com.codeskraps.talarkam.TalarkamActivity.onResume(TalarkamActivity.java:108)
08-03 14:40:26.154: E/AndroidRuntime(255):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1149)
08-03 14:40:26.154: E/AndroidRuntime(255):  at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3763)
08-03 14:40:26.154: E/AndroidRuntime(255):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2937)
```

Comment: 108 =   Log.d(TAG, "onPause");

Comment: I edited your post. The problem isn't that it won't compile. Obviously it compiles just fine. The problem is that it won't run.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is here in `onResume()`:

```
Uri alarmUri = Uri.parse(prefs.getString(TONE, null));
```

If this preference doesn't exist, it defaults to `null`, which causes NullPointerException.

**EDIT Added code suggestion to get rid of NPE**

Replace this code in your `onResume()`:

```
Uri alarmUri = Uri.parse(prefs.getString(TONE, null));
Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, alarmUri);
if (ringtone != null) {
    String name = ringtone.getTitle(this);
    btnSetTone.setText(name);
} else
    btnSetTone.setText(getString(R.string.btn_SetAlarmTone));
```

with this code:

```
Ringtone ringtone = null;
String toneString = prefs.getString(TONE, null);
if (toneString != null) {
    Uri alarmUri = Uri.parse(toneString);
    ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, alarmUri);
}
if (ringtone != null) {
    String name = ringtone.getTitle(this);
    btnSetTone.setText(name);
} else {
    btnSetTone.setText(getString(R.string.btn_SetAlarmTone));
}
```

Comment: Hmm, How to fix this problem ?

Comment: I don't know the application. it looks like there should be something stored in the shared preferences with the key `TONE`, but there isn;t anything there. Go look in the code where you set that value in the shared preferences and see if that is being executed.

Comment: private static final String TONE = "tone";

Comment: Well, I'm assuming that the preference TONE should have been stored there by some other activity that calls this one. There isn't anything obvious in the code you posted.

Comment: Code from MainActivity still not much help. In any case, I've edited my answer to show how you can get around the NullPointerException. Maybe this will get you further so that you can resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't posted the whole code, it's tricky to figure out exactly the line it's failing (line 108?). But my guess is that the following line is the root cause:

Uri alarmUri = Uri.parse(prefs.getString(TONE, null));

It can't find the TONE key/object in the prefs and sets the default to null.

Comment: private static final String TONE = "tone";